# Xamarin Forms fade out animation isn't working

Tags: c#, xamarin, animation, xamarin.forms

I'm having difficulties with the FadeTo extension method. The fade out works, but when fading in, it does not animate, the view just appears. This happens on both iOS and Android. Here is my code:

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task FadeTaskView(bool appear)
{
    if (appear)
    {
        await _Scroller.FadeTo(1, 250, Easing.Linear);
    }
    else
    {
        await _Scroller.FadeTo(0, 250, Easing.Linear);
    }
}

private async void OnCalendarDateChanged()
{
    await FadeTaskView(false);

    Tasks.Load(_TaskBackingStore.Where((t) =>
        t.Due.Date == CalendarDate.Date
    ));

    await FadeTaskView(true);
}
```

When I remove/comment out the Tasks.Load line the animations works fine.

Any ideas welcome.

As a workaround I have amended the code to look like the below. It seems to work smoothly but with a performance cost on iOS:

```
    private async void OnCalendarDateChanged()
    {
        var tasksToShow = _TaskBackingStore.Where((t) =>
            t.Due.Date == CalendarDate.Date
        ).ToArray();
        
        await FadeTaskView(false);

        Tasks.Load(tasksToShow);

        if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(750);

        await FadeTaskView(true);
    }
```

Comment: Try to call the `FadeTaskView(true);` in Main thread:          `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
                await FadeTaskView(true);
            });`.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you are running the animations on a background thread.

We can leverage `Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync` to ensure that animations are happening on the Main Thread (aka the UI Thread).

```
private System.Threading.Tasks.Task FadeTaskView(bool appear) => Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(async () =>
{   
    if (appear)
    {
        await _Scroller.FadeTo(1, 250, Easing.Linear);
    }
    else
    {
        await _Scroller.FadeTo(0, 250, Easing.Linear);
    }
}

private async void OnCalendarDateChanged()
{
    await FadeTaskView(false);

    Tasks.Load(_TaskBackingStore.Where((t) =>
        t.Due.Date == CalendarDate.Date
    ));

    await FadeTaskView(true);
}
```

Comment: After adding this in it works well on Android however, iOS the problem still occurs. I would image if the animations were not running on the UI Thread to begin with an exception would have been raised - which was not the case.

Comment: Clean & Re-build both your Xamarin.Forms project and your iOS project to ensure the new changes have been properly deployed

Comment: I'm afraid after cleaning and rebuilding both the projects the issue still persists on iOS

Comment: Try temporarily increasing the animation time to 2500ms to ensure it is animating

Comment: Done but, what happens on iOS is that it starts to FadeIn then after a few milliseconds the bound collection updates to what's required (Tasks.Load line), then it continues to complete fading in. I'm hoping that when the bound collection changes it remains invisible to the user. The bound collection is databound to the UI through a dependency property. Not sure why this is happening on iOS.